# Android ksoap object mapping

Tags: android-ksoap2

### How can I map the response of SoapObject to MyObject using KvmSerializable?

I read wiki on ksoap2-android. But still cant do it.

I added a map to the envelope:

```
envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "return", new GoodsObject().getClass());
```

But I get an exception:
**java.lang.ClassCastException: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject**
on the string

```
GoodsObject resultsRequestSOAP = (GoodsObject) envelope.bodyIn
```

The code is below.
I spent much time on this problem but still have no ideas (

---

Java class **GoodsObject**:

```
    package com.deaddy64.droid;

    import java.util.Hashtable;

    import org.ksoap2.serialization.KvmSerializable;
    import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;


    public class GoodsObject implements  KvmSerializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    public String ref;
    public String DeletionMark;
    public String Code;
    public String Description;


    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4872313975732374054L;

    public void setref(String strref) {
        this.ref = strref;
        }

    public String getref() {
        return this.ref;
        }

    public void setDeletionMark(String strDeletionMark) {
        this.DeletionMark = strDeletionMark;
        }

    public String getDeletionMark() {
        return this.DeletionMark;
        }

    public void setCode(String strCode) {
        this.Code = strCode;
        }

    public String getCode() {
        return this.Code;
        }

    public void setDescription(String strDescription) {
        this.Description = strDescription;
        }

    public String getDescription() {
        return this.Description;
        }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.ksoap2.serialization.KvmSerializable#getProperty(int)
     */
    public Object getProperty(int index) {
        switch (index) {
           case 0:
               return ref;
           case 1:
               return DeletionMark;
           case 2:
               return Code;
           case 3:
               return Description;

    }
        return null;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.ksoap2.serialization.KvmSerializable#getPropertyCount()
     */
    public int getPropertyCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 4;
    }



    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.ksoap2.serialization.KvmSerializable#setProperty(int, java.lang.Object)
     */
    public void setProperty(int index, Object value) {
        switch(index) {
        case 0:
            this.ref = value.toString();
            break;
        case 1:
            this.DeletionMark = value.toString();
            break;
        case 2:
            this.Code = value.toString();
            break;
        case 3:
            this.Description = value.toString();
            break;
        default:
            break;


     }

    }

    public void getPropertyInfo(int index, Hashtable properties,
            PropertyInfo info) {
        switch (index) {
           case 0:
               info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
               info.name = "Ref";
               break;
           case 1:
               info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
               info.name = "DeletionMark";
               break;
           case 2:
               info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
               info.name = "Code";
               break;
           case 3:
               info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
               info.name = "Description";
               break;

    }
        }
    }
```

This is **ResponseDump**:

```
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Header/>
    <soap:Body> <m:getReferenceResponse xmlns:m="com.deaddy64">
    <m:return xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <Ref xmlns="http://v8.1c.ru/8.1/data/enterprise/current-config">7f4fb970-6a62-11e1-9bd0-001fd027b6bb</Ref>
        <DeletionMark xmlns="http://v8.1c.ru/8.1/data/enterprise/current-config">false</DeletionMark>
        <Code xmlns="http://v8.1c.ru/8.1/data/enterprise/current-config">000000003</Code>
        <Description xmlns="http://v8.1c.ru/8.1/data/enterprise/current-config">123</Description>
    </m:return>
</m:getReferenceResponse></soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

In debugger **envelope.bodyIn** is:

```
      (org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject) getReferenceResponse{return=anyType{Ref=7f4fb970-6a62-11e1-9bd0-001fd027b6bb; DeletionMark=false; Code=000000003; Description=123; }; }
```

Main activity:

```
    package com.deaddy64.droid;

    import java.io.IOException;

    import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
    import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
    import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
    import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
    import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;


    public class Droid1Activity extends Activity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);


            myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {



                    String NAMESPACE = "com.deaddy64";
                    String URL = "http://10.0.2.2/InfoBase/ws/ws1.1cws";
                    String SOAP_ACTION = "com.deaddy64#testService:getReference";
                    String METHOD_NAME = "getReference";    


                    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
                    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

                    //envelope.dotNet = true;

                    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                    envelope.addMapping("http://v8.1c.ru/8.1/data/enterprise/current-config", "CatalogObject.Номенклатура", new GoodsObject().getClass());

                    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                    androidHttpTransport.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>");
                    androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
                    Log.v("dd64", "xml");
                    GoodsObject resultsRequestSOAP;
                    try {
                         // List<HeaderProperty> headerList = new ArrayList<HeaderProperty>();
                          //headerList.add(new HeaderProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + org.kobjects.base64.Base64.encode("username:password".getBytes())));
                        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                        resultsRequestSOAP = (GoodsObject) envelope.getResponse();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Log.v("dd64",androidHttpTransport.requestDump);
                    Log.v("dd64", androidHttpTransport.responseDump);




                }
            });
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "GoodsObject", new GoodsObject().getClass());
```

and

```
GoodsObject resultsRequestSOAP = (GoodsObject) envelope.getResponse();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried this. No changes.
I think the problem is because of type of response (anyType) as I see it in a debugger. But I dont know why it is.

Comment: Ok, I think that you also need to add the getters and setters to `GoodObject` class.

Comment: I added setters and getters to my class. But no effect.

Comment: Well, could you put all the code relative to ksoap-calling web service method? (sorry for my English)

Comment: It seems ok. My last try: Ksoap is very "special" about member names, so I think this `info.name = "Ref";` in `getPropertyInfo` method,  should be `info.name = "ref";`

Comment: Hi! After few days of breaking my brains I get the result:
My SOAP server is built-in the popular Russian framework for business applications called "1C:Enterprise" [link](http://www.1c-dn.com/).
My problems was because of errors in this framework. It generated not correct response without types.
After updating version of "1C" the problems were gone. And now mapping mechanism working correct! Thanks for helping.